# Google Analytics - Same URL mapped to two pages

Tags: google-analytics

I have my application configured with google analystics. Its a e-learning application in which i have students and instructors. 
I want to analysze the home page clicks for both student and instructor. The problem is the home page for student is also available in instructor but as some other page means same URL but different locations.

Now, i have added the script in ONLY student's page. By doing this though i have mapped the URL for an instructor page as well, will that effect the analysis? Will the data collected for students home page be affected by click on same link for instructor  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a single page that both students and instructors go to, then yes, your data will all show up under the same URL, and you will not be able to tell which views are from students and which are from instructors.

If you have the code ONLY populating when a student is on the page, then yes, this will affect your reports. You will be able to see how many students are viewing the page, but you will not know anything about the instructors viewing the page.

There are 2 things you can do with the GA code to get your numbers:

1) Report a different URL or page name depending on who is viewing.  By default, GA reports the URL as the page name, but there is an optional 2nd argument to the [_trackPageview](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview) call on your page that lets you specify what you want the page name to be. This will make your pages reports show two different entries.

2) Populate a [custom variable](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCustomVar) on the page. This will show all traffic to the same page, but you will be able to use the custom variable to see how much of the traffic is from who.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer was for the Classic GA snippet. For the latest GA snippet (Universal), you'd want to go with this.

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': '/my-overridden-page?id=1',
  'title': 'my overridden page'
});
```

See [*Overriding Default Values* in the GA Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages).